# I get gibberish characters instead of stack trace on ASP.NET website with customErrors=off

Tags: asp.net, exception, web-config

I have a simple web-site.

When customErrors=On in web.config, the user is redirected to the custom error page correctly

However, I have an exception I want to track down, so I disabled customErrors by flipping the setting in web.config to Off.

Now I do not get redirected, but get a bunch of gibberish characters on the screen instead (which confirms the setting did take place).

It looks like this:

��Yos�8ߙ~-7�e������Y��f��Sr��t2�l��X^I�2���H2`�$&i�}�Τ`Y�=�I?�*�?���� �Q�~��M?�s��w�,�I��s�������$B1g>�F4&�䯄i���2�gi�n$    �p�#��p�� S�`0�Xd� 3    ��|��l�;��m�y"nm��0�:�x@�C��N�ȭObI{ASݰk���b±�SIn���Lq�'���cpO���ٔu_�*'�`�!����z�z�ؕZ�fW��ٯ4��� pj��� �Yn�D ��ExDK7��c�ei���Ҙrx�꓊~(�jv���<��`���P�� '��g��RK��  e3b|�C3$�� t��|2��B�_���n�hd���F��&��ķ߲���XF<��z���~,S!*� �GB6f��1�͢Ɯ,�"�B,Jۥw�O��)m�����$o�qE�֊q@Q4k�1���^J��`�\Ca�e�G���h���%������TXE,"�((p���.]8�x�8��Vs���cR�Qٵ�vi�m��{!x-KN��peS�$F�s�o&�=���Z���#P���    �x��#|k ��v���o�.���� �0b`o?d�&d-�GT��LS-��9�a��@OBw����E}����{@7g_��ݭf�[M7��Q� o�]�F�S���A��Q�=��ٖ}�Z�u�8��������Ю���T��&@������VgE��i#���K?p_�m�H�{%D��P2��������@D%�~�A"r��$��HT>�Abp�PO�p�G9����1����i0n�k���Hp�]r��u�����-�����Ps!S>����  � I�@?�hĠ�h�W \�a�%҈��jb�fI�8�V�%�%��BZ��A��_�ѳ����P�Ϩϙ`}iO�@@}au������x�l��T �y���l��^���U��X�X�!ʹ��*��C��/�?g��}������ ����� w\�Sa�����4���:�7.�n��8`���KG��g���}!*-`ڧ�A"� Lgek�#�'C�ٕcs5�!0��>Ra� e~x��J��*�.�*�^�T�&1~Dw�/~z[x���u�#tOO�cm���"�>w�$���\^:W�u��p&.���e; [�3���$��*2����K�6�T��DH2�·4U��9�B��ٸ۟�������+��a5�G>��1ߏ@��n�i8�[� �I(�@��S�!Q�|� ������@yi����� b0-��B�Z�h����ӌ���Xi��Nqp����!ܜ`KW��̇����<{W�I�woG!`4�}LE�I�-4�#5���Q�Z�՞�^�G^�/GDYP> ���C�h��F��������յF68J����hgJ��҇S�T���?{̀ǘc�LRb��|"}e ��鉒�    Rߠ�2�ґm�=�z=��+gQ�c;y���FrW�'��|f�/����/ ܯ�^�����N�_^� pb!��fU�/T��Pa�e�����RZ���=`0�]3f�P_L 7т������o�&�ek��(���N}����(k��_�.bt�`�yG�3�c�S����m�E(�o��ރ`��:�]?���v!���6����>0�ڟ�    t�_xT{b������r��o�k2��/����{y ��ێ>�����Է6���3|M>3�L�RКv��Ơ�W�\�L�`Ēii�A���@�.���!_8�c؅�K�$ ������yV�zP�5r��A@9��-i�1఩rݨ��<�|�D�3�u�#�� /��h�)��A�8�8T7��U�w����Z�m��x��vs�<��y�=�2�PE���^��<���L/�=I��<-.�wgNKLU�^����YHW���E0���x�7�-<����$�$o8�y �V�-����9T�����}�)CX�N��zr�ު�?f��˚ �f�ku���:��z��ծe�v,{ElUѺ�����ru�c�/� Z�"\����#���.��2��^!r�������J��%�P6K<���=�(F ����{ ��L�A,��y��5B��7X#�gb 6T�m���vJ <��q��֯���H��#/�<�ci�'��XR�A���ă�7 $�a=��X#&s\ɷ��!�rs8��!(�m�����<�^�[�2S�64œ�e�.��<�bSQ���G��X��Żmȋ5hT��O\�Y�"HEI��m܀�x�;P9B�Ʉ��`W��X�[�~U���Ƭsj�-

How can I fix this so I actually see the stack trace and what not?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Can you tell what browser this is and what its language settings are set to?

Comment: It was Google Chrome (English language)

Comment: Internet Explorer behaves even more strange:
It suggests I download the file Display?cmp=USMF, which is part of the web-site URL:
https://localhost:8999/Execute/Display?cmp=USMF